# Let $L \in \mathbb R$. Suppose that $\{a_n\}$ converges to Provide a complete and accurate $\epsilon-N$ proof that $\{a_n^2\}$ converges to $L^2$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $L \in \mathbb R$. Suppose that $\{a_n\}$ converges to Provide a complete and
accurate $\epsilon-N$ proof that $\{a_n^2\}$ converges to $L^2$

Attempt:

$\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N > 0$, such that for all $n \in \mathbb N$, if $n > N$, then $|a_n - L| < \frac{\epsilon}{M+|L|}$ where $|a_n| \leq M, \forall n \in \mathbb N$

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be arbitrary

Choose N such that $|a_n - L| < \frac{\epsilon}{M+|L|}$

Suppose $n > N$, then $$|a_n^2 - L^2| = |a_n-L|\cdot|a_n+L|$$

$$\leq|a_n-L| \cdot (|a_n| + |L|)$$

$$< \frac{(M + |L|)\epsilon}{(M + |L|)}$$

$$= \epsilon$$

As required

Is this right?

Comment: All convergent sequences are bounded so the way you define M is not needed.

Comment: How do I define M then?

Comment: Take $ | a_n -L | < \epsilon / M +|L| $ where $|a_n| \leq M $ for all n. Then your proof works just fine.

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: You need to read and study [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2234597/prove-that-if-a-n-converges-to-l-in-mathbbr-then-a-n2-converge/2234756#2234756).

Comment: that $\{a_n^2\}$... what?

Comment: Whoop I didnt copy it properly. Still you should be able to get what it converges too I think, changed.

Comment: Title and intro to this  question are so lousy that you deservedly obtained no answer so far.

Comment: To be fair there was no valid question to answer for 8 hours because I didn't realize I wrote the title/question wrong. What does the intro have to do with anything? Also my question was answered I just didn't realize it was a repost by someone else were above pointed out.